# CSS force div with absolute position be behind div with static position

Tags: javascript, html, css

So lets say that I have some document

```css
        #a{width: 10px; height: 10px; background: red; z-index: 10;}
        #b{width: 100%; height: 100%; background: black; z-index: 5; position: absolute;}
```

```html
    <body>
        <div id="a">foo</div>
        <div id="b">bar</div>
    <body>
```

The `#b div` covers the `#a`, because `#b` has `absolute` position.

How can I **force `#b` be behind `#a`** without changing #a position?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add `position: relative` to `#a` element.

Comment: Yeah, I found it out right after posting the question, my bad ) thanks anyway

Comment: #a{width: 10px; height: 10px; background: red; z-index: 10; position:relative}

Answer (score 2):

You have to set a `position` other than `static` to your first div to apply styles like `z-index`

```css
#a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}

#b {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">foo</div>
<div id="b">bar</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add a relative position to your first div :

```
<body>
    <div id="a">foo</div>
    <div id="b">bar</div>
<body>
<style>
    #a{width: 10px; height: 10px; background: red; z-index: 10; position:relative}
    #b{width: 100%; height: 100%; background: black; z-index: 5; position: absolute;}
</style>
```